# Import Capacitor Community plugin into a vanilla js script

Tags: javascript, cordova, capacitor

I have a basic app written in pure javascript (index.html, script.js) which i put into a `CapacitorJs` project to let me create ios/android apps. which work perfectly fine even on my phone.

But now i'm trying to use a capacitor community plugin ([@capacitor-community/contacts](https://github.com/capacitor-community/contacts)) but i need to import it in my script.js like this

`import { Contact, Contacts, NewContact } from '@capacitor-community/contacts';`

Since i'm not using typescript it obviously throw an error.

How can i manage to make it work ?

- I have tried to import it through a `<script type="module">` on my index.html and assign it to the js global `window` variable to access it in my script.js but it doesn't work.
- I have also tried to convert my scripts.js to a typescript and compile it with the following config:

```
{
  "target":"es5",
  "module":"es2015",
  "moduleResolution:"node"
}
```

And to make it work, had to change the import string to:
`import { Contact, Contacts, NewContact } from '../../nodes_modules/@capacitor-community/contacts';`

But then i get an error on the console saying `TypeError: 'text/html' is not a valid Javascript MIME type`

- I ve tried also with the following config

```
  "target":"commonjs",
```

But got error with "define" not being recognized in the browser.

- I am also aware of `"bundledWebRuntime": true`, that basically compile capacitor core files into a .js that you import in your index.html. But it doesn't include community packages so it's not a solution.

Comment: are you using any bundler like webpack or rollup? does your project have a package.json?

Comment: i have package.json for my capacitor project. I don't use any bundler. I just use `npx cap sync`

Comment: can you share the error you're getting and where exactly (file & line) it's occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with typescript. Your project must be declared to use ES modules, in order to use features such as `import`. I'm a bit unclear on your exact setup, but if you have a `package.json`, then try adding this to it:

```
{
  ...
  type: "module",
}
```

If you just have a basic setup, i.e. html page with a js file in a script tag, you should be able to get it to work by declaring your js file as a module like this:

```
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: the only `package.json`  i have is for the Capacitor project which contain capacitor `dependencies` & `devDependencies`. Then i have a subfolder called `www` where i put my `index.html` and `script.js`

Comment: check my edit for including the module type in the script type. otherwise i'm afraid i'm out of ideas.

Comment: thanks a lot i ve managed to do it through the webpack package. [More information here](https://medium.com/@SmileFX/a-complete-guide-building-a-capacitorjs-application-using-pure-javascript-and-webpack-37d00f11720d)